# The removing page has already been flushed

Tags: java, itext7

I created a PDF file with the data from an Excel file. I am not sure what was happened, but when I tried to remove one PdfPage and insert it somewhere else, it showed the warning message "The removing page has already been flushed".

The used code is quite simple:

```
PdfDocument pdf = ...;
....
PdfPage page = pdf.removePage(10);
pdf.addPage(1, page);
```

But I got warning and errors:

> [main] WARN com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage - The removing page has
>   already been flushed.  Exception in thread "main"
>   com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException:flushed.page.cannot.be.added.or.inserted
>     at
>   com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.checkAndAddPage(PdfDocument.java:1473)
>     at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.addPage(PdfDocument.java:437)

To be honest, I did have tried the above code with some other PDF files, it works to remove and to insert pages. What could be the possible reasons with my PDF file?

Complete code used in my application:

```
PdfWriter writer;
PdfDocument pdfDocument;
Document document;
try {
        writer = new PdfWriter(FileConfigurator.getAbsoluteResultFilePath(), 
                new WriterProperties().addXmpMetadata().setPdfVersion(PdfVersion.PDF_1_7));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

//Initialize PDF document
pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
// Initialize document
document = new Document(pdfDocument);
```

Comment: `pdf.copyPagesTo(10, 10, pdf, 1); pdf.removePage(10+1);` as workaround. Maybe you already wrote the document? As in `flush = write buffer` instead of `flush = flushed through the toilet`.

Comment: Basicly it means that prior the removing of page, the page you are removing was actually written into the output stream. The same piece of code can work on different input, but this does not proof anything.

Comment: The default behaviour for iText7 is to flush early and often, to limit the amount on memory needed during execution. The exception signifies that that particular page has already been written to the outputstream, and as such can't be manipulated in the code anymore. @Joop Eggen's code should result in the behaviour you desire. In general, when inserting and moving around exisitng pages, `copyPagesTo` should be your default method.

Comment: The `pdf.copyPagesTo(10, 10, pdf, 1);`  will trigger a NullPointerException, I think we should copy it to another `topdf` for the parameter. My generated PDF file has now already more than 60 pages with pictures inside, but still is it possible to forbidden to flush the PDF?

Comment: Can you show exactly how you create your document? I mean the part that you marked as `...`. Are you using `Document` from `layout` module to create the content?

Comment: I think I found the problem: the "flushed" problem will occur if I have lot of TOC pages (I hat 6 TOC pages in my PDF); but when I tried to reduce the TOC pages to 2, program works as disigned.