# page X of Y with re-ordered TOC: X will start from 1 again after the TOC

Tags: itext7

I could create **seprately** the "page x of y" and re-ordered the TOC with the official examples. "Page x of y" is created according to iText 7: Building Blocks [Chapter 7: Handling events; setting viewer preferences and writer properties](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-7-handling-events-setting-viewer-preferences-and-writer-properties) with the examples **Solving the "Page X of Y" problem**; and TOC is created with reference to iText 7 examples [**TOC as first page**](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-examples/itext-7-bookmarks-tocs/toc-first-page).

Now I want the generated PDF to have both "page x of y" and re-ordered TOC. And "page x of y" shall be shown on all pages, i.e. on the 1st page (the TOC page), it shall show "Page 1 of 35", the 2nd page (start page of the main text) shall show "Page 2 of 35" (In this Jekyll and Hyde example, TOC has one page).

But when I tried to put "page x of y" and re-order TOC together, I found a problem in the generated PDF: the 1st page (the TOC page) showed correctly "Page 1 of 35", but the 2nd page (start page of the main text) showed also "Page **1** of 35".

What is the tricks to let the 2nd page to show "Page 2 of 35" with re-ordered TOC?

==code for Page X of Y and re-order TOC==

```
package main;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.itextpdf.io.IOException;
import com.itextpdf.io.font.FontConstants;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.Event;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.IEventHandler;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.PdfDocumentEvent;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFont;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfName;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutline;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfString;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.action.PdfAction;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.PdfCanvas;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.draw.DottedLine;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.navigation.PdfDestination;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.xobject.PdfFormXObject;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Canvas;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.AreaBreak;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Tab;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.TabStop;
import com.itextpdf.layout.hyphenation.HyphenationConfig;
import com.itextpdf.layout.layout.LayoutContext;
import com.itextpdf.layout.layout.LayoutResult;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.AreaBreakType;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.TabAlignment;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.TextAlignment;
import com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.ParagraphRenderer;

public class CreateTOC {


    public static final String SRC = "D:/work/java_workspace/result/jekyll_hyde.txt"; 
    public static final String DEST = "D:/work/java_workspace/result/test_toc.pdf"; 

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, Exception { 

        File file = new File(DEST); 
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs(); 
        new CreateTOC().createPdf(DEST); 
    }

    public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, java.io.IOException { 

        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest)); 
        pdf.getCatalog().setPageMode(PdfName.UseOutlines); 

        PageXofY event = new PageXofY(pdf);
        pdf.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, event);

        PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.TIMES_ROMAN); 
        PdfFont bold = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA_BOLD); 

        Document document = new Document(pdf); 
        document.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED) 
               .setHyphenation(new HyphenationConfig("en", "uk", 3, 3)) 
               .setFont(font) 
               .setFontSize(11); 

//      // add the cover
//      document.add(new Paragraph("this is the cover 1"));
//      document.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE)); 
//      
//      
//      document.add(new Paragraph("this is the cover 2"));
//      document.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE)); 

        // parse text to PDF 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(SRC)); 
        String name, line; 
        Paragraph p; 
        boolean title = true; 
        int counter = 0; 
        PdfOutline outline = null; 
        List<SimpleEntry<String,SimpleEntry<String, Integer>>> toc = new ArrayList<>(); 
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
            p = new Paragraph(line); 
            p.setKeepTogether(true); 
            if (title) {

                name = String.format("title%02d", counter++); 

                outline = createOutline(outline, pdf, line, name); 

                int pagesWithoutCover = pdf.getNumberOfPages();

                SimpleEntry<String, Integer> titlePage = new SimpleEntry(line, pagesWithoutCover); 

                p.setFont(bold).setFontSize(12) 
                          .setKeepWithNext(true) 
                          .setDestination(name)
                          .setNextRenderer(new UpdatePageRenderer(p, titlePage)); 
                title = false; 

                document.add(p); 
                toc.add(new SimpleEntry(name, titlePage)); 
            } 
            else {
                p.setFirstLineIndent(18); 
                if (line.isEmpty()) { 
                    p.setMarginBottom(12); 
                    title = true; 
                } 
                else {
                    p.setMarginBottom(0); 
                } 
                document.add(p); 
            } 
        } 

        document.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE)); 

        // create table of contents 
        int startToc = pdf.getNumberOfPages();        
        p = new Paragraph().setFont(bold).add("Table of Contents").setDestination("toc");
        document.add(p); 
        toc.remove(0); 
        List<TabStop> tabstops = new ArrayList(); 
        tabstops.add(new TabStop(580, TabAlignment.RIGHT, new DottedLine())); 
        for (SimpleEntry<String, SimpleEntry<String, Integer>> entry : toc) { 

            SimpleEntry<String, Integer> text = entry.getValue(); 
            p = new Paragraph() 
                 .addTabStops(tabstops) 
                 .add(text.getKey())
//               .setFixedLeading(150)
                 .add(new Tab()) 
                 .add(String.valueOf(text.getValue())) 
                 .setAction(PdfAction.createGoTo(entry.getKey())); 

            document.add(p); 
        } 
        int tocPages = pdf.getNumberOfPages() - startToc; 

        // reorder pages 
        PdfPage page; 
        for (int i = 0; i <= tocPages; i++) { 
            page = pdf.removePage(startToc + i); 
            pdf.addPage(i + 1, page); 
        } 

        event.writeTotal(pdf);
        document.close(); 
    } 

    protected class UpdatePageRenderer extends ParagraphRenderer { 

        protected SimpleEntry<String, Integer> entry; 
        public UpdatePageRenderer(Paragraph modelElement, SimpleEntry<String, Integer> entry) { 

            super(modelElement); 

            this.entry = entry; 
        } 

        @Override 
        public LayoutResult layout(LayoutContext layoutContext) { 

            LayoutResult result = super.layout(layoutContext); 
            entry.setValue(layoutContext.getArea().getPageNumber()); 
            return result; 
        } 
    } 



    public PdfOutline createOutline(PdfOutline outline, PdfDocument pdf, String title, String name) { 

        if (outline ==  null) { 
            outline = pdf.getOutlines(false); 
            outline = outline.addOutline(title); 
            outline.addDestination(PdfDestination.makeDestination(new PdfString(name))); 
            return outline; 
        } 

        PdfOutline kid = outline.addOutline(title); 
        kid.addDestination(PdfDestination.makeDestination(new PdfString(name))); 
        return outline; 
    } 




    protected class PageXofY implements IEventHandler {

        protected PdfFormXObject placeholder;
        protected float side = 20;
        protected float x = 300;
        protected float y = 25;
        protected float space = 4.5f;
        protected float descent = 3;

        public PageXofY(PdfDocument pdf) {
            placeholder = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(0, 0, side, side));
        }

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
            PdfDocument pdf = docEvent.getDocument();
            PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
            int pageNumber = pdf.getPageNumber(page); 

            Rectangle pageSize = page.getPageSize();
            PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(
                page.newContentStreamBefore(), page.getResources(), pdf);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdf, pageSize);
            Paragraph p = new Paragraph().add("Page ").add(String.valueOf(pageNumber)).add(" of");

            canvas.showTextAligned(p, x, y, TextAlignment.RIGHT);
            pdfCanvas.addXObject(placeholder, x + space, y - descent);
            pdfCanvas.release();
        }

        public void writeTotal(PdfDocument pdf) {
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(placeholder, pdf);
            canvas.showTextAligned(String.valueOf(pdf.getNumberOfPages()),
                0, descent, TextAlignment.LEFT);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Concerning your edit I guess you now finally should show your code as that behavior is not explainable with only those referenced examples in mind which you put together.

Comment: Ok, i added the whole Java file.

Comment: Cf. the edit to my answer; the added offset works at least in the current iText development snapshot version.

Answer (score 0):

#### In general

You will obviously run into trouble if you first create pages including a "page x/y" using the current page number of each page and then re-order the pages.

If you know beforehand how many pages you will move up front, you can take this re-ordering into account by adding this number as offset to the page number in your event listener. Be sure to reset that offset when you start creating the TOC pages.

If you don't know that number, it does not make sense to try to number the pages before re-ordering at all. Instead add page numbers afterwards as described in the iText 7: Building Blocks [Chapter 2: Working with the RootElement](http://developers.itextpdf.com/de/node/3184) example **Adding a Page X of Y footer**, i.e. loop over every page in the document and add a "Page X of Y" `Paragraph` to each page:

```java
int n = pdf.getNumberOfPages();
Paragraph footer;
for (int page = 1; page <= n; page++) {
    footer = new Paragraph(String.format("Page %s of %s", page, n));
    document.showTextAligned(footer, 297.5f, 20, page,
        TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE, 0);
}
document.close();
```

Don't forget to set `immediateFlush` to `false` as described right after that example.

#### Using an offset

In a comment you indicated that you did not want to use the solution from chapter 2 referenced above as you didn't want to keep the whole PDF in memory. Then you posted your code.

Thus, let's try and implement the offset mentioned above in your code.

The offset variable is best located right in the event listener. Having added it, it might looks like this:

```java
protected class PageXofY implements IEventHandler
{
    // vvv added
    int offset = 0;
    // ^^^ added

    protected PdfFormXObject placeholder;
    protected float side = 20;
    protected float x = 300;
    protected float y = 25;
    protected float space = 4.5f;
    protected float descent = 3;

    public PageXofY(PdfDocument pdf)
    {
        placeholder = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(0, 0, side, side));
    }

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event)
    {
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
        PdfDocument pdf = docEvent.getDocument();
        PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
        int pageNumber = pdf.getPageNumber(page); 

        Rectangle pageSize = page.getPageSize();
        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(
            page.newContentStreamBefore(), page.getResources(), pdf);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdf, pageSize);
        // vvv changed
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph().add("Page ").add(String.valueOf(pageNumber + offset)).add(" of");
        // ^^^ changed

        canvas.showTextAligned(p, x, y, TextAlignment.RIGHT);
        pdfCanvas.addXObject(placeholder, x + space, y - descent);
        pdfCanvas.release();
    }

    public void writeTotal(PdfDocument pdf)
    {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(placeholder, pdf);
        canvas.showTextAligned(String.valueOf(pdf.getNumberOfPages()),
            0, descent, TextAlignment.LEFT);
    }
}
```

*([PageXofY](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/content/CreateTOC.java#L249))*

(You might want to add getters and setters for the offset.)

When importing the text body your page numbers currently are created off-by-one as the TOC page will later be pulled up to the front. Thus, you need to use an offset of 1 (1 page TOC) during that import.

Afterwards, before starting the TOC page, you will have to reset the offset to 0 as nothing will be pulled before the TOC page thereafter.

Id est:

```
public void createPdf(Reader reader, String dest) throws IOException
{
    [...]

    Document document = new Document(pdf); 
    document.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED) 
           .setHyphenation(new HyphenationConfig("en", "uk", 3, 3)) 
           .setFont(font) 
           .setFontSize(11); 

    // vvv added
    event.offset = 1;
    // ^^^ added

//  // add the cover

    [...]

    document.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE)); 

    // vvv added
    event.offset = 0;
    // ^^^ added

    // create table of contents 
    int startToc = pdf.getNumberOfPages();
    [...]
}
```

*([CreateTOC](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/content/CreateTOC.java#L93) method `createPdf`)*

In the current iText 7 development 7.0.3-SNAPSHOT version this results in desired page numbering.

Beware: There had been reports on delayed page event execution. Probably the event timing meanwhile has been changed. With older versions, therefore, the code might still apply wrong page numbers.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will not use the approach in Chapter 2: Working with the RootElement, since I have a document more than 150 pages, I am not sure if my old computer has enough memory not to flush the content till the page x of y has been created.  So I will workaround it assume that I know the number of TOC pages beforehand since it does not change often in my application. But I don't understand your sentence "Be sure to reset that offset when you start creating the TOC pages." As what I observed is that when the TOC page is re-ordered to 1st page, page 1 of Y is generated correctly on it.

Comment: @cao *"But I don't understand your sentence ..."* - As soon as you are starting to create the TOC pages, your event listener should not add the offset anymore, otherwise your TOC pages won't start with 1/Y anymore.

Comment: This looks like "eine Sackgasse". Sorry my initial problem description is not complete, please refer to my updated description. You can see only PDF page 2 and last page are not correctly generated in case of 1 page of TOC. More interesting is what if the TOC page has more than 1, so I tried to set the line space of the TOC to 100 `setFixedLeading(100)` which resulted 2 pages of TOC. The PDF pages vs. Page X of Y is then: 1 - Page 1 of 36, 2 - Page 3 of 36, 3 - Page 1 of 36, 4 - Page 3 of 36, 5 - Page 4 of 36, ..., 36 - Page 35 of 36. I have no clue any more.

Comment: That's why I asked you in a comment to your question to share the relevant parts of your code. You *tried to put "page x of y" and re-order TOC together* and seem to have done it wrong, but without seeing the code it is hard to tell what exactly you did wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried, as I am still using 7.0.2, it doesn't work for the last page only with 2 pages TOC. I will wait release of 7.0.3 to have a try again. By the way, please try my code in 7.0.3 with changing the line space for the TOC `setFixedLeading(150)`, 150 will generate exactly two full pages of TOC and if you increase it it to 160, TOC will be generated with **3** pages, it will cause an error "The removing page has already been flushed." which I have posted before in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39569739/the-removing-page-has-already-been-flushed).